# How much antimatter can we theoretically hold in a Minimum Magnetic Field Trap?

Tags: science-based, electromagnetism, antimatter

I will be using [solar antimatter production](https://newatlas.com/antimatter-starship/23345/) via [Schwinger pair production](https://journals.aps.org/prd/abstract/10.1103/PhysRevD.98.036008) like the VARIES project but I need to store it for bulk use. The containment will be a satellite orbiting the sun close enough to draw the energy needed. This is a question of scale.

I want to store my antimatter in a [Minimum Magnetic Field Trap](https://newscenter.lbl.gov/2010/11/17/antimatter-atoms/) orbiting the sun, for use later as a propellant.

## Is there a theoretical size limit to MMFT antimatter containment, or is there another method which can achieve large scales?

Comment: This question might fare better over at physics.stackexchange.com

Comment: Why are you shouting?

Comment: Those are not caps?

Comment: Turns out that caps are **not the only way to provide emphasis anymore**. One of the benefits of living in the future, you see.

Comment: a bit discouraged that they achieved " researchers recorded 38 antihydrogen atoms, which had been held in the trap for ***almost two-tenths of a second***"

Answer (score 2):

There seems to be a lot of unknowns with the theoretical technology you suggest, so the only way to really determine the size limit is to look at what we have now and scale-up. Storing antimatter on a large scale in the simplest way might be an array of MMFT containers. This way you can apply what we know to be true, and use minimal "magic science". The scale can be extremely large so I think this solution would be viable.

Comment: What's MMFT? Google is thinks I need a doctor or something.

Comment: @JohnDvorak the OP used it as a stand-in for a Minimum Magnetic Field Trap.

Comment: The only problem with that is if I need a 1 ton apparatus to hold an atom of anti-matter pretty soon I'll have a miniature black hole to slingshot my rocket off of rather than using it for it's original purpose. TL;DR you can't ever assume things work the same outside of the same magnitude they actually work in (_*cough cough_* Quantum _*sneeze_*)